# code block inside table row in Markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am putting together some documentation in Github flavoured Markdown and I want to put together a table that has two rows. One with simply text and one with a json code block. Heres an example.

```
| Status | Response  |
|---|---|
| 200 |  |
| 400 |   |
```

I want to get this code inside the response row but when ever I try it completely breaks.

```
json
  {
    "id": 10,
    "username": "alanpartridge",
    "email": "alan@alan.com",
    "password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS",
    "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.",
    "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z"
}
```

I am new to Markdown and if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Code block inside Markdown table row [with syntax highlighting ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77774604/8644294)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The github markdown doc states that you can include inline/span markdown tags within table cells. This is the same for most flavours of markdown other than a few which have been trying to establish more control over table layouts.

You could get close with inline code elements, but that will not format with syntax colouring, or line indents.

```
| Status | Response  |
| ------ | --------- |
| 200    | `json`                          |
|        | `   {`                          |
|        | ` "id": 10,`                    |
|        | ` "username": "alanpartridge",` |
|        | ` more code...`                 |
|        | `}`                             |
| 400    |                                 |
```

Alternatively, create your table the old-fashioned way with html, which gives you `rowspan` for greater layout control.

Comment: You don't need rowspan if you use old fashioned html.  The browser will do the right thing.  Just embed code into <pre> tags.  (you don't get the MD language-specific code syntax highlighting)

Comment: This doesn't render very well actually.

Comment: This code renders several lines of code, but each one in a different background

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below that solves the mentioned rendering issues and allow a full, markdown code block in a single table cell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60502719/3063

Answer (score 73):

You'll have to use HTML `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags to create the table, but you can format the content of table cells using Markdown.

**Leave extra blank lines inside the HTML tags around the Markdown content.** Inside tables, leave a blank line after the `<td>` and one before the `</td>`, otherwise the Markdown inside won't be displayed. (Technically this creates a new `<p>` paragraph inside the cell, and Markdown parsing is re-enabled inside paragraphs.)

````
<table>
<tr>
<td> Status </td> <td> Response </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 200 </td>
<td>

↑ Blank line!
```json
json
{
    "id": 10,
    "username": "alanpartridge",
    "email": "alan@alan.com",
    "password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS",
    "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.",
    "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z"
}
```
↓ Blank line!

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 400 </td>
<td>

**Markdown** _here_. (↕︎ Blank lines above and below!)

</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

[image: Preview image of the table created with the code above on GitHub]

(If you want to fix the bad vertical alignment between "400" and "Markdown here", add blank lines around the "400" too, which will wrap that in a `<p>` as well.)

Comment: Thank you! Not just extra blank lines mess the whole table up, <tab>'s does as well. Github flavoured markdown can be really "funny" some times 

Answer (score 47):

## Github Flavored Markdown Supports HTML Tag

[image: github markdown table-code]

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>
Status
</th>
<th>
Response
</th>
</tr>

<tr>

<td>
<pre>
<br/><br/><br/>200<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>400<br/>
</pre>
</td>

<td>
<pre>
json
  {
    "id": 10,
    "username": "alanpartridge",
    "email": "alan@alan.com",
    "password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS",
    "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.",
    "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z"
}
</pre>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

<sub>**[Markdown Editor](https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/)** can really be helpful to visualize output as you write.</sub>

<sub>Instead of `<pre>` tag we may also use triple-backticks ```` ``` ```` for showing a code block.</sub>

---

**EDIT:** You may also try text-based table like this-

```
+---------------+--------+---------+
|       \       | Rating | Comment |
+---------------+--------+---------+
| One Piece     |  A | B |       ♢ |
+---------------+----+---+---------+
| Naruto        |  A | C |       ♧ |
+---------------+----+---+---------+
| One Punch Man |  A | A |       ♥ |
+---------------+----+---+---------+
| Death Note    |  A | B |       ♠ |
+---------------+----+---+---------+
```

<sub>**[Text Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)** is a wonderful site for this purpose.</sub>

---

**EDIT 2:** The following code works both for GitHub and StackOverflow-

```
| Name | Signature Code                 |
|------|--------------------------------|
| Minhas Kamal | <pre>main(m,k){<br>  for(<br>    ;<br>    m%k--?:(k=m++);<br>    k^1?:printf("%i\|",m)<br>  );<br>}</pre> |
```

Output-

| Name | Signature Code |
| --- | --- |
| Minhas Kamal | ``` main(m,k){ for( ; m%k--?:(k=m++); k^1?:printf("%i|",m) ); } ``` |

Comment: But why backticks ``` won't work in text based tables?

Comment: @IvanAracki For making the table look exact we need to have a mono-spaced font. And for that, we are putting the whole table in a code block. And we cannot write a code block  inside of a code block. Backtics (```) can be used in HTML tag though.

Comment: Reading your answer, it sounds like it's not possible in markdown to have a markdown table where some of the table cells are code blocks. Can the html be used to display such a table in stackoverflow/exchange though? I had a similar question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372523/how-to-properly-embed-a-code-block-into-a-markdown-table-cell-alternatively-ho?noredirect=1#comment1244017_372523.

Comment: Seems, we cannot depend on pure Markdown in this case. Markdown is actually a simplified **incomplete** iteration of Markup language.

Answer (score 25):

This one maybe better:

```
| Status | Response  |
| ------ | --------- |
| 200    |<pre lang="json">{<br>  "id": 10,<br>  "username": "alanpartridge",<br>  "email": "alan@alan.com",<br>  "password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS",<br>  "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.",<br>  "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z",<br>  "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z"<br>}</pre>|
| 400    |<code>{<br>  "code": 400,<br>  "msg": balabala"<br>}</code>|
```

Both of them need the `<br>`, it depends on you like the `<pre>` or `<code>`.

---

In stackoverflow, the above displays as:

| Status | Response |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | { "id": 10, "username": "alanpartridge", "email": "alan@alan.com", "password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS", "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.", "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z", "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z" } |
| 400 | `{ "code": 400, "msg": balabala" }` |

Which doesn't display the `<pre lang="json">` block as code.

---

However, in stackoverflow, removing the `lang="json"` from `<pre>` does display the entire `<pre>` block as a code block. That is:

```
| Status | Response  |
| ------ | --------- |
| 200    |<pre>{<br>  "id": 10,<br>  "username": "alanpartridge",<br>  "email": "alan@alan.com",<br>  "password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS",<br>  "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.",<br>  "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z",<br>  "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z"<br>}</pre>|
| 400    |<code>{<br>  "code": 400,<br>  "msg": balabala"<br>}</code>|
```

displays as:

| Status | Response |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | ``` { "id": 10, "username": "alanpartridge", "email": "alan@alan.com", "password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS", "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.", "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z", "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z" } ``` |
| 400 | `{ "code": 400, "msg": balabala" }` |

Comment: The `lang="json"` attribute on the `<pre>` tag is very useful to know.

Comment: The `<br>` tag doesn't work inside the `pre` and `code` tags!

Comment: The `lang="json"` part solved my problem of wanting to syntax highlight the code snippet inside the table cells!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It was what I need to answer this other question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372524/1084071

Comment: It seems that adding the `lang=` attribute to `<pre>` tags causes nested `<br>` tags to no longer work in GitHub Flavored Markdown. However, you can work around it and get a multi-line code block with working syntax highlighting by replacing the `<br>` tags with the HTML escape character for newlines (`&#13;`).

Comment: Looks like the markdown interpreter influences the results because <br /> works fine in my environment and the <code> tag is closer to answering the question than the <pre> tag.

Answer (score 3):

## Code block inside Markdown table row with syntax highlighting

### GitHub version

```
| Status | Response  |
| ------ | --------- |
| 200    |Some code here:<br><pre lang="json">{&#13;  "id": 10,&#13;  "username": "alanpartridge"&#13;}</pre>|
| 400    |Some text here|
```

The above markdown is displayed as:

[image]

### StackOverflow version

```
<!-- language-all: json -->

| Status | Response  |
| ------ | --------- |
| 200    |Some code here:<br><pre><code>{<br>  "id": 10,<br>  "username": "alanpartridge"<br>}</code></pre>|
| 400    |Some text here|
```

The above markdown is displayed as:

| Status | Response |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | Some code here: ```json { "id": 10, "username": "alanpartridge" } ``` |
| 400 | Some text here |

[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372524)

Answer (score 0):

```
Status | Response
:----- | :-------
200    | <code>json {"id": 10,"username": "alanpartridge", "email": "alan@alan.com",<br>"password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS", "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.",<br> "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z", "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z" }</code>
400    | <code>json {"id": 10,"username": "alanpartridge", "email": "alan@alan.com",<br>"password_hash": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.CPCWCZsyqqa8./whhfzBZydX7yvahHS", "password_salt": "$2a$10$uhUIUmVWVnrBWx9rrDWhS.",<br> "created_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.433Z", "updated_at": "2015-02-14T20:45:26.540Z" }</code>
```

Comment: This doesn't get the multi-line formatting of the code block. All the json is presented on the same line (with wrapping, perhaps).

Comment: This answer is the closest to resolving the question.  @Gabe is right about the multi-line, however, just adding <br /> after each line resolves this problem.  The question is about code blocks, but the example is JSON, so all the answers focus on the example and not the question.